# Радеть о/за?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно писать “радеть о” или “радеть за”. Правильно ли употребление предлога  в выражении “радетели за демократию”?

Answer (score 3):

Еще недавно слово воспринималось как устаревшее.Значение его подзабылось.По Ушакову:1. (•совер. порадеть) кому-чему и о чем. Оказывать содействие, заботиться о ком-чем-нибудь, проявлять усердие по отношению к кому-чему-нибудь (•устар.). Радеть друзьям. Радеть о деле. Теперь его путают с "ратовать"(говорить в защиту, заступаться) Ратовать за кого .
Даже в печати часто путают их управление: Радетели за правовое государство (Лит. газета, 1993, 13 янв.)

Так что правильно: радеть кому-чему и о чем; ратовать за кого-что. Возможно, когда-нибудь произойдёт контаминация значений, т.к. это уже употребляется сплошь и рядом, и узаконится управление "радеть за", но пока в словарях этого нет.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! Я нашел в поисковиках то же самое. Вроде бы однозначно "радеть О", но смущает огромное количество выражений “радеть за” (чистоту русского языка, например). К тому же спор у меня вышел с руководящим работником, так что хотелось бы отыскать документ, где явно было бы написано, что "радетель о", или вообще без предлога. Радетель русского языка. Радетель о русском языке. За русский язык радетель. Но не радетель за русский язык.
Синонимы подставлял покровитель, ценитель, заступник, защитник.  Для ратовать, думаю, больше подходит синоним бороться, сражаться. Поэтому ЗА.

Comment: Документ - словарь, хотя бы Ожегова. Или любой в Интернете.